# Go Lang + Vim + Syntastic + goimports - make it work with AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, vim, go, syntastic

I'm using vim to write AppEngine code.  There are two useful plugins that don't work well.

Syntastic: It shows the appengine imports as errors.
goimports (https://github.com/bradfitz/goimports): I've added an issue on that project as well with the same issue that it does not recognize appengine imports.

Is there a way to fix this?

thanks

Comment: Well... you did well by submitting an issue to the author/maintainer. Fixing a bug in his plugin is his job, not ours.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a bug or my lack of knowledge.  Additionally since it is something I noticed with Syntastic also, I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: Try copy appengine pkg source code and .a file to your GOPATH

Answer (score 0):

The following (unofficial) appengine syntastic checker should work (automagically):

https://github.com/roktas/syntastic-more

**P.S.** For the reasons depicted in [the relevant comment](https://github.com/roktas/syntastic-more/blob/master/after/syntax_checkers/go/appengine.vim#L1-L5), this checker is a bit dirty hack and has not yet been submitted to the official Syntastic repo.  Please use Github Issues for bugs.